# USB camera for streaming

Tags: camera

I need to stream the video to the monitor in real time. I am using the USB camera module(ELP-USB130W01MT-L21) interfaced with the Rpi(through SSH). Streaming USB camera and Rpi camera module are same or should i follow the different procedure?? If yes! kindly explain the same.

Thanks

Comment: Streaming a USB camera and the Pi camera module are fundamentally different operations; the Pi camera module is handled by the GPU which gets to draw directly on the HDMI/composite output if it wants to (in other words the CPU doesn't even need to "see" the frames). The USB bus doesn't get to do that so you have to grab frames from the USB camera and render them on-screen (i.e. it takes CPU time to render the video output)

Comment: well, so how to stream the video using USB camera?

Comment: I'd start by looking at the source of simple webcam apps, e.g. [cheese](https://git.gnome.org/browse/cheese/tree/) or [guvcview](https://sourceforge.net/p/guvcview/git-master/ci/master/tree/). In guvcview it looks like it's a matter of setting the camera capturing continually, hooking up a callback to receive the frame data, and having the callback render the frame data in some window. In cheese, it looks like it's using GStreamer to do something similar.

Comment: I hope i could achieve it( streaming video) using few Linux command which i am not sure about. Since i am new to Linux i am finding difficult with the commands or method to be implemented. I installed the mplayer and used this command `mplayer tv:///dev/video0`.but the video is inappropriate.

Comment: Oh, if you just want to view the output of the webcam then simply install one of those viewers, e.g. `sudo apt-get install guvcview` then run guvcview and you should see the output easily (I thought since you mentioned "streaming" you were wanting a solution you could code yourself)

Comment: yup. I tried it. i installed guvcview. but command `guvcview` is not resulting to video. its giving error.  `GUVCVIEW: couldn't open /home/pi/.config/guvcview2/video0 for read: No such file or directory` also connection errors.