# watch live video through hdmi using USB cam

Tags: camera, hdmi

I  have connected the monitor to the pi via HDMI. 
I would like to figure out a way to get a live video playing on the monitor.
( not over a network)
I know there is a answer for this question here.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57841/watch-live-video-through-hdmi-on-rpi?noredirect=1&lq=1

But in my case `i am using USB camera module,not the pi camera.` 
kindly suggest.

Comment: Which Pi do you have? Which OS are you using? Do you want to do this from the GUI or from the command-line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stream video from raspberry Pi camera and watch it live](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live)

Comment: I am using raspberry pi 3 and working with Linux. And yes,  I wanna do this with command line.

Comment: Well it was the same question but i am using USB camera. I hope all the answer mentioned above there are for pi camera. can i consider the same answers for USB cam too?

Comment: Duplicate of earlier question: [USB camera for streaming](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58741/usb-camera-for-streaming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have VLC installed (if you don't, it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install vlc`) and an X server running, you can run

```
vlc v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0
```

to see live video from the camera.

You can also use parameters from [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/v4l2/) to change video settings like this:

```
vlc v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 :v4l2-width=640 :v4l2-height=480
```

Comment: Hi,  I have tried it, `v4l2 demux error: dequeue error:no such device` this is the error I am getting. In the pi's desktop environment I installed VLC and tried to play the video with the command you mentioned above. media player was opened with the blank black screen.