# Stream from USB webcam to rpi3+ hdmi screen

Tags: pi-3b+, streaming-video, webcam

I'm looking for something I think should be simple, but haven't been able to find any resource that shows how to do it.

I have a USB webcam attached to my PI 3+. I also have a monitor attached to the HDMI port. I'd like to display what the webcam sees on that monitor.

I'm not looking to stream over my local network, or to the web, YouTube, etc. Just display the video on the monitor attached to the pi.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Nope, nothing yet.

Comment: Maybe this answer will be good for you: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59322/watch-live-video-through-hdmi-using-usb-cam